# How can MapView fill a full parent container?

Tags: android

There is the following simple layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/activityMainPoints"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:apiKey="0JsSnv022MOCCXMAJfsQTVtfCiH37VG5XykFLmQ"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, the MapView must fill the full parent container RelativeLayout, but it isn't! How can I fix it?

Comment: can you show a screenshot as well ?

Comment: is google maps api v1 or v2?

Comment: I use api v1 and a real device

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activityMainPoints"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="0JsSnv022MOCCXMAJfsQTVtfCiH37VG5XykFLmQ"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
```